# AddressBook not loading

Tags: c#, xml, addressbook

This is my source code it works fine, but it has one problem. It does not load the XML file that I followed at youtube because this is supposed to be a project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Addressbook_Csharp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1");
        if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml"))
            File.Create((path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml"));
        {
            XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
            xW.WriteStartElement("People");
            xW.WriteEndElement();
            xW.Close();
        }
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People"))
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            p.Address = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Address").InnerText;
            p.Contacts = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            p.Email = xNode.SelectSingleNode("Email").InnerText;
            p.Birthday = DateTime.FromFileTime(Convert.ToInt64(xNode.SelectSingleNode("Birthday").InnerText));
            people.Add(p);
            listView1.Items.Add(p.Name);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = textBox1.Text;
        p.Address = textBox2.Text;
        p.Email = textBox4.Text;
        p.Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        p.Contacts = textBox3.Text;
        people.Add(p);
        listView1.Items.Add(p.Name);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return; 
        textBox1.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name;
        textBox2.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address;
        textBox3.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Contacts;
        textBox4.Text = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Remove();
    }

    void Remove()
    {
        try
        {
        listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
        people.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void removeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Remove();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return; 
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Name = textBox1.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Address = textBox2.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Contacts = textBox3.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Email = textBox4.Text;
        people[listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index].Birthday = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
    }


    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml");
        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("People");
        xNode.RemoveAll();
        foreach (Person p in people)
        {
            XmlNode xTop = xDoc.CreateElement("Person");
            XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            XmlNode xAddress = xDoc.CreateElement("Address");
            XmlNode xContacts = xDoc.CreateElement("Contacts");
            XmlNode xEmail = xDoc.CreateElement("Email");
            XmlNode xBirthday = xDoc.CreateElement("Birthday");
            xName.InnerText = p.Name;
            xAddress.InnerText = p.Address;
            xContacts.InnerText = p.Contacts;
            xEmail.InnerText = p.Email;
            xBirthday.InnerText = p.Birthday.ToFileTime().ToString();
            xTop.AppendChild(xName);
            xTop.AppendChild(xAddress);
            xTop.AppendChild(xContacts);
            xTop.AppendChild(xEmail);
            xTop.AppendChild(xBirthday);
            xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xTop);
        }
        xDoc.Save(path + "\\Address Book - Group 1\\settings.xml");
    }
    class Person
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public string Address
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public string Contacts
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public DateTime Birthday
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you already have data in your xml file ? Because if you don't or it isn't created, your application will create one but it will be empty (a Person element without any data in it).
Did you check the `xDoc.Save()` was properly executed when you close your application after filling some fields ?

Comment: `works perfectly fine but it has one problem` :)

Comment: Nevermind guys I solved it already. I just switched the xmlwriter and the reader. The reader goes first then the writer. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Friendly advice : use brackets even if you only have ne line in a `If` block, it' more readable. If you don't make sure to have a line executed if your condition is met and the rest of the method body. (Hope i was clear enough)